# не могу подключиться к pg, ошибка без ошибки

Tags: python, postgresql

облазил весь интеренет, но так и не нашел информации, даже в документации. Первый раз подключаюсь к postgresql, сначала пытался через sqlalchemy, потом уже напрямую, вылезает одна и та же ошибка без каких-либо пояснений, помогите пожалуйста. Пользователя я создал заранее, pgadmin запущен, версия pg - 16, работаю на win10, пишу на питоне
ошибка:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\projects\programming\python\bots\freelance\tg\penny_bot\test.py", line 256, in <module>
    connecton = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost user=xakum password=QWEqwe123 dbname=pennydb")
  File "d:\projects\programming\python\bots\freelance\tg\penny_bot\penny_venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError
```

код:

```
import psycopg2

connecton = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost user=xakum password=QWEqwe123 dbname=pennydb")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я решил свою проблему установив другой драйвер. Поскольку у меня не было задачи подключиться к бд именно с помощью драйвера pycopg2, я решил попробовать использовать другой драйвер - pg8000 https://pypi.org/project/pg8000/
подключение в sqlalchemy теперь выглядит так

```
engine = create_engine("postgresql+pg8000://xakum:password@localhost:5432/penny_db", echo=False) # подключение к базе данных pg
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine) # создание сессии
session = Session() # создание сессии
Base = declarative_base() # создание базового класса
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте подключение для psycopg2 в таком формате.
Но база данных должна быть уже создана.

```py
connecton = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", user="xakum", password="QWEqwe123", dbname="pennydb", port="5432")
```

Comment: да, я пробовал, но это не решило проблему